# Why is my request returning incomplete multipart?

Tags: arduino, jetty, multipartform-data, multipart

I am using my Arduino to do a multipart/form-data request. I am generating the request completely by myself as follows:

```
client.println(HTTP_METHOD + " " + PATH_NAME + " HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: " + String(HOST_NAME));
  
    client.print(F("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; "));
    client.print(F("boundary=\"AaB03x\"\r\n"));
    client.print(F("Content-Length: "));
    client.print(strlen("{json data here}") 
    + strlen("{json data here}"));
    client.print("\r\nConnection: close\r\n");
    // First part 

    // Boundary 
    client.print(F("\r\n--AaB03x\r\n"));

    // Headers
    client.print(F("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"header\"\r\n"));
    client.print(F("Content-Type: application/ld+json\r\n"));
    client.print(F("Content-Length: "));
    client.print(strlen("{json data here}"));
    client.print(F("\r\n\r\n"));

    // Content 
    client.print(F("{json data here}"));

    // Second part 

    // Boundary 
    client.print(F("\r\n--AaB03x\r\n"));

    // Headers
    client.print(F("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"payload\"\r\n"));
    client.print(F("Content-Type: application/ld+json\r\n"));//
    client.print(F("Content-Length: "));
    client.print(strlen("{json data here}"));
    client.print(F("\r\n\r\n"));

    // Content 
    client.print(F("{json data here}"));

    // End of boundary 
    client.print(F("\r\n--AaB03x--\r\n\r\n"));
```

However the server returns "Incomplete multipart" which I don't understand since the multipart seems completely fine. I thought it was maybe due to incorrect newlines but I haven't been able to figure out a solution.

The output can be seen below and includes the request sent as well as the response from the server.

```
GET /router HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.178.147
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="AaB03x"
Content-Length: 4363
Connection: close

--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="header"
Content-Type: application/ld+json
Content-Length: 4143

{
   some data here
}
--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="payload"
Content-Type: application/ld+json
Content-Length: 220

{
   some data here
}
--AaB03x--

connected to 192.168.178.147
HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
Connection: close
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 597
Server: Jetty(9.4.41.v20210516)

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500 Server Error</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/router</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>500</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Server Error</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>org.apache.camel.component.jetty.CamelContinuationServlet-38cb1606</td></tr>
<tr><th>CAUSED BY:</th><td>java.io.IOException: Incomplete Multipart</td></tr>
</table>
<hr><a href="https://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.41.v20210516</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `strlen` for calculating `Content-Length`, as `strlen` returns the count of characters, you want the count of bytes (this becomes especially important for unicode/utf-8).

Answer (score 0):

Your `Content-Length` calculations are suspect.

Drop the `Content-Length` headers for each sub-section in the multipart and try again, those are not needed for multipart, and your calculations are just wrong anyway.

You can see captures of various multipart requests from various libraries and browsers in the Jetty tests.

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/jetty-9.4.41.v20210516/jetty-http/src/test/resources/multipart

(Look at the ones ending in `*.raw`, which you can generally open in a text editor)

Tip: don't do this yourself, multipart mime is full of edge cases, traps, and ancient tricks.  Go grab apache httpcomponents httpmime jar and just use it to generate your raw mime multipart section properly.

- Artifacts - https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime
- Javadoc - https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/latest/index.html

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply. I dropped the `Content-Length` headers, however the response from the server is still that the multipart is incomplete unfortunately.

I took a look at the example from github as well and they seem similar to my request.

Comment: You still have the main HTTP `Content-Length` request header to fix. it's incorrectly calculated for the body of the http request. (remember it's the count of bytes, not characters)  Do yourself a favor and capture the request/response traffic with a tool like Wireshark and it will highlight issues for you (like the bad content-length header)